# React Dropbox Component using Material-UI-Next

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Is there a way to nest a dropdown component with MenuItem? I would like to declare one component whenever I need to use a drop down instead of nesting two. 
Am I on the right path or should drop down components be handled differently than normal React components?

App.js (this currently works nesting MenuItem within DropDown)

```js
<DropDown
  label="Drop Down Label"
  value={this.state.selectedState}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
  {stateAbbreviationData.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</DropDown>;
```

App.js (how I would like to use my component, does not work)
Shows code `(data.map(option => (   ))}  )` instead of a list when clicked. Further code below.

```js
<DropDown
  label="Drop Down Label"
  value={this.state.selectedState}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  menuData="stateAbbreviationData"
  menuKey={stateAbbreviationData.value}
  menuValue={stateAbbreviationData.value}
  menuOptionLabel={stateAbbreviationData.label}
/>;
```

DropDown.js

```js
import React from "react";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import DropDownMenu from "./DropDownMenu";

const styles = {
  minWidth: 175
};

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        select
        label={this.props.label}
        value={this.props.value}
        style={styles}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        margin="normal"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        menuData={this.props.menuData}
      >
        <DropDownMenu
          key={this.props.menuKey}
          value={this.props.menuValue}
          optionLabel={this.props.menuOptionLabel}
        />
      </TextField>
    );
  }
}
export default DropDown;
```

DropDownMenu.js

```js
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/Menu/MenuItem";

const styles = {
  minWidth: 175
};

class DropDownMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.menuData.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={this.props.key} value={this.props.value}>
            {this.props.optionLabel}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDownMenu;
```

StateAbbreviationData.js

```js
const stateAbbreviationData = [
  {
    value: "AL",
    label: "AL"
  },
  {
    value: "AK",
    label: "AK"
  }

  // ...
];

export default stateAbbreviationData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first example is the one that you want to create with your `DropDown` component. Try removing `DropDownMenu` component, and doing all of the logic inside `DropDown`:

```js
import React from "react";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/Menu/MenuItem";

const styles = {
  minWidth: 175
};

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        select
        label={this.props.label}
        value={this.props.value}
        style={styles}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        margin="normal"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
      >
        {this.props.menuData.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```

And then you can use it the way you want to:

```js
<DropDown
  label="Drop Down Label"
  value={this.state.selectedState}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  menuData={stateAbbreviationData} // <-- Put in braces
/>
```

**Note:**
With Material UI, I've used `MenuItem` components inside of the `Select` component, rather than the `TextField` component like you're doing:
https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/

---

There were a couple issues with your existing code I'll point out.

As I indicated above, you need to pass the data `stateAbbreviationData` into the `DropDown` component's props using curly braces:

```js
<DropDown
  label="Drop Down Label"
  value={this.state.selectedState}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  menuData={stateAbbreviationData} // <-- This change
  menuKey={stateAbbreviationData.value}
  menuValue={stateAbbreviationData.value}
  menuOptionLabel={stateAbbreviationData.label}
/>
```

There's another bug with the way you're setting the `menuKey`, `menuValue`, and `manuOptionLabel` props. With the code you included, it seems like `stateAbbreviationData` is an array of objects.

In the props, you're trying to access properties on that array that don't exist: `stateAbbreviationData.value` and `stateAbbreviationData.label`. The objects in the array have those bits, but the array itself doesn't.

```js
<DropDown
  label="Drop Down Label"
  value={this.state.selectedState}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  menuData={stateAbbreviationData}
  menuKey={stateAbbreviationData.value}  // <-- Doesn't exist
  menuValue={stateAbbreviationData.value} // <-- Doesn't exist
  menuOptionLabel={stateAbbreviationData.label}  // <-- Doesn't exist
/>
```

There's also a bug where you're passing `menuData` to the `TextField` component, but instead you should pass it to `DropDownMenu`.

That said, I recommend going with the first solution I proposed. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Reed! Yes! I arrived at the same answer. Sorry for my delay in getting back.